# TypeError with python json data

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I've been trying to parse some data from json and I am having some difficulty getting the data out of my json.load set.

```
for obj in menus:
    if("parent_id" not in obj):
        rootItem = {"root_id": obj["id"], "child_ids": obj["child_ids"]}
        roots.append(rootItem.copy())
    else:
        for r in roots:
            if(obj["parent_id"] == r["root_id"]):
                r["child_ids"].append(obj["child_ids"])
```

I receive at rootItem line; typeError: List indices must be integers, not str

I am not sure why, I am creating a dictionary with the values being pulled from obj.

Any help is great!

edit:
this is a sample of the data that I am accessing and trying to create a dictionary from to put back into a json output.

```
[[
{"child_ids": [3], "data": "House", "id": 1}, 
{"child_ids": [4, 5, 8], "data": "Company", "id": 2}, 
{"child_ids": [7], "parent_id": 1, "data": "Living Room", "id": 3}, 
{"child_ids": [], "parent_id": 2, "data": "Meeting Rooms", "id": 4}
]]
```

Comment: You're creating a dictionary, but you're presumably *accessing* a list: `obj`. If you want proper help, you should show the data you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually iterating a list within a list.
You should do something like `for obj in menus[0]:` to iterate the dictionaries in the inner list (that's  applicable if you only have one list within `menus`).